# find sum of all the rows in sql table which are related in second table

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I have two mysql tables

```
+--------+-------+
| parent | child |
+--------+-------+
| A      | B     |
| B      | C     |
| C      | D     |
| D      | E     |
| F      | F     |
+--------+-------+
```

Here Child is Subsidiary of Parent company.
and

```
+---------+----------+
| account | bookings |
+---------+----------+
| A       |      100 |
| B       |       20 |
| C       |       40 |
| D       |       60 |
| E       |       10 |
| F       |        5 |
+---------+----------+
```

I need to write a sql query to get following output

```
+---------+----------+
| A       |      230 |
| F       |        5 |
+---------+----------+
```

Output is the sum of all the columns in second table who has subsidiaries, grouped by parent company. In this case A has subsidiary as B which has susidiary as C and so on.

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you've got to do. Do you have a question? Why has the been tagged Excel?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Dave Removed the incorrect tag. I am trying to find the query. I was working with joins but could not find a solution.

Comment: So what have you tried? Do you have a partial query already? Do you need to do this in one query or would multiple work?

Comment: @Seth one query will be great. But if multiple queries can solve this, I am good with that too.

Comment: Does the second have multiple entries or the account a PK? Start by writing a `SUM` query for that table? I'm not sure ... you could try a self join for the first. Did you already try that?

Comment: PK are serial numbers (1...100). I tried SUM query on second table but that's not solution if subsidiaries in first table increases in future.

Comment: You should add those queries regardless and as you need those sums it's a partial solution. Write now this would be kind of off topic as it's just asking for a solution without actually supplying any information on what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I set up some test tables to replicate the schema and data you've described:

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts(
    Parent VARCHAR(1),
    Child VARCHAR(1)
)

CREATE TABLE Bookings (
    Account VARCHAR(1),
    Bookings INT
)

INSERT INTO Accounts
SELECT 'A','B'
UNION
SELECT 'B','C'
UNION
SELECT 'C','D'
UNION
SELECT 'D','E'
UNION
SELECT 'F','F'

INSERT INTO Bookings
SELECT 'A', 100
UNION
SELECT 'B', 20
UNION
SELECT 'C', 40
UNION
SELECT 'D', 60
UNION
SELECT 'E', 10
UNION
SELECT 'F', 5
GO
```

I would create a scalar function to return the "top level" parent of any given Account:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnAccountTopParent (@Account VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Parent VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @Child VARCHAR(1)

    SET @Child = @Account
    SELECT @Parent = Parent FROM Accounts WHERE Child = @Child

    WHILE (@Parent IS NOT NULL AND @Parent <> @Child)
    BEGIN
        SET @Child = @Parent
        SELECT @Parent = Parent FROM Accounts WHERE Child = @Child
    END

    RETURN @Child

END
GO
```

This function can then be used in a query to get the desired result:

```
SELECT  dbo.fnAccountTopParent(Account) AS Account,
        SUM(Bookings) AS Bookings
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY dbo.fnAccountTopParent(Account)
```